# What is this coat of arms?

Tags: nobility, heraldry

This is on a chair that has been in my family in Sweden for several generations, but it looks to be of British origin rather than Scandinavian.

I am still new to heraldry but the terms martlet, crosslet, and roundlet might be used to describe some of the imagery in the shield.

Might anyone be able to help me further identify the coat of arms. It is possible that the coat is just decorative and never belonged to a family - if this is so, is there any way to know when it was made?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the History Exchange Stack. Can we get a full picture of the chair? Are there any markings under/ on the back of it? Are there any family stories on where it came from?

Comment: The fact that the cross bottony (I just learnt this heraldic term for this type of cross) is found 5 times, especially repeated on lions make me think that it's not "just decorative". This kind of cross bottony is often found in orthodox countries ; being in Sweden, don't you think an origin on the other side of the Baltic see is possible ? Slightly connected, the coat of arms of Korwyn family in Poland :https://www.wikiwand.com/en/%C5%9Alepowron_coat_of_arms

Comment: I can't quite tell if it's intended to be *per fess indented* or *a chief indented*. I also can't tell whether the crosses are *crosslet* (square) or *bottony* (rounded), but in either case, they're also *fitchy* (the bottom limb is replaced by a pointed end). The bird at the top is, indeed, a *martlet* (you can tell because it doesn't have feet). The circular things are not roundels (or roundlets, which isn't a heraldic term), but *annulets*.

Comment: Oh, and the crosses on the shield are *in bend* (and *bendwise*, but that might be assumed from the *in bend*).

Comment: Putting it all together (and assuming it's intended to be a chief, based on the horizontal arrangement of charges): *In bend three crosses crosslet fitchy, on a chief indented a martlet between two annulets.*